# Masstransit consumer raw message

Tags: c#, json, rabbitmq, masstransit

Someone put a message in RabbitMq (for example). The message is not in the Masstransit "envelop" format, just `json`, or maybe something else.
How to get this message in Masstransit consumer as `byte[]`, or `string`?

I understand that Masstransit has its own message format, but there is a need to receive a raw message. I don’t really like the option when Masstransit and RabbitMq client are used in one service, because these are already two connections, and different message processing logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the receive endpoint where raw JSON messages are to be consumed, you can configure a default deserializer as shown:

```cs
endpointConfigurator.UseRawJsonDeserializer(isDefault: true);
```

Comment: The mystery is easily solved ) Thanks a lot